# Chrome-cast is not listing wifi

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Recently I reset my router for certain reasons, So when I am trying to connect it to chromecast, Chromecast is not listing my wifi name in its list.

Earlier it was working fine, So I choose other and put my network name manually and entered password but it gave me error as chromecast Can't find `wifi network` I am proving screenshots regarding that.

[image: Displaying Network list]

[image: Manual Entry]

After this It gave me error message `Chrome-Cast cant find your wi-fi network`.

I tried restarting of router, restarting of chrome-cast but same problem is there. As I mentioned, earlier it was working now it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your wifi router hasn't switched to 5GHz; chromecast only works with 2.4 GHz.

Answer (score 6):

Also what channel are you using? Chromecast only supports US legal channels at the moment, so no Channel 13 or 14

Comment: Got my Chromecast in Czech Republic. It does not officially sell here but you can get it from aftermarket. I think it is the North American version since it only sees 11 channels.

Comment: Works for me. I was using channels 13, 14 (they are legal in my country - Czech Republic). Thank you very much.

Comment: Worked for me, it was on channel 12 so I changed to 9

Answer (score 0):

My Chromecast could not find my network either.

I am using a Dlink dir-635 router.

My solution was to use WPA2-AES Only no mixing.

and of course remember to enable Multicast streaming and disable WLAN partition

Comment: If we're keen on rules, I'm more concerned that this question is on SO and has nothing to do with programming.  This isn't a tech support page.  That said, it did reveal the root cause of the problem to I've been having.  My Belkin router stopped broadcasting the 2.4GHz, devices only camp on the 5GHz SSID.  Chromecast only supports 2.4GHz.